# Fade in/out whole view exept one subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I try to recreate an effect in the Path app : when you tap a photo/video all the views fade in except the one you just tapped which goes fullscreen.

I wonder how such effect is done because if you change the alpha of your main view, all subviews are affected including the one you want to stay visible. If you do a for loop to change the alpha of all subviews exept the photo, the background will keep its colour.

The only way I can think of is to do the for loop through all subviews and to set the background colour to black. But in my opinion it's not really clean code.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of discussion, let's consider two views, the "thumbnail" view that contains the grid of smaller images, and the "detail" view that animates in size and position to fill the screen.

By thinking of these views separately, the animations become easier to manage. Clicking on an item in the "thumbnail" view causes that view to fade out and a new "detail" view containing a copy of the clicked item to appear in the same position and animate to full screen.

Comment: Strictly speaking, to get the Path effect, you'll need to remove the image view and add it on top (not another copy).  It separates from the frame, leaving a gray background where the picture was formerly "mounted".

Answer (score 2):

What about putting a `UIView` in front of everything with a background of white at 0.5 alpha (this can be animated from 0->0.5 to get the fade effect you want).

Then, move the photo you don't want to fade infront of that so it's not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about this.

1. Make sure the action is only possible when the scroll view is not scrolling (optional)
2. Disable scrolling on the scroll view
3. Use the UIView Coordinate conversion methods ("convertRect:fromView:" and 
   "convertRect:toView:") to calculate the new frame for the image view.  The new target superview can be the application's keyWindow, or another full screen subview if you'd like.  There are a number of ways to do this, since there are several views involved (the frame view, a possible table cell content view, the scroll view, etc.), so I'd recommend planning a test that will help you quickly understand when the expected and actual coordinate translations are.
4. Remove the image view from its superview
5. Add the image view at the converted rect to the full screen view or keyWindow
6. Add the animations (alpha = 0 for the background, resize (and optionally rotate) for the image view).  Animating alpha = 0 for the view controller which formerly held the image view will fade to black just fine as long as there is another view with a black background behind it. You could also just host 2 views in the view controller, one a plain black UIView, and the other (on top of the black) would host all the views you want to fade.  Then, you only have to change the alpha on that one view and all its subviews will fade.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can put a small thumb an when user click on it change alpha value for all view and add a new view with the same image at highest resolution.